# Error undefined function mysqli_connect on Cron Job

Tags: php, cron, webmin, virtualmin

I have a problem executing a Cronjob with Virtualmin and Nginx. I have to execute a php script.
When I execute it with cronjob I have this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /home/ivirgin/public_html/check.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/ivirgin/public_html/check.php on line 36

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /home/ivirgin/public_html/check.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/ivirgin/public_html/check.php on line 36
```

While, if I execute the script without cronjob but writing address on browser, I have not errors.

This is the command that I inserted in Cronjob:

```
php -f /home/ivirgin/public_html/check.php
```

Can anyone help me to solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: Check to see what dependencies the script is using when running via the cron. Insert `php_info();` to your script and run the cron to see the output. It may be pulling a separate php.ini file that doesn't have `mysqli` enabled

Comment: '*While, if I execute the script without cronjob but writing address on browser, I have not errors.*' - Are you sure error reporting is enabled?